# CartThrob packages field really slow

Tags: cartthrob, packages

Running EE: 2.7.2 and CT: 2.4

I have a packages channel in my CT configuration for product bundles. It's using the packages field. I'm trying to figure out why it makes the page run really slow in the backend when trying to add a new entry to that channel. **This is also causing problems on our productions site: 508 Resource Limit Has Reached**

**Debugging**

After some debugging I've found that when I load the publish page first time around the PHP is processing for **40 seconds** after the page has loaded.

It runs this query twice:

`SELECT cd.*, ct.*, c.* FROM exp_channel_titles ct JOIN exp_channel_data cd ON cd.entry_id = ct.entry_id JOIN exp_channels c ON c.channel_id = ct.channel_id`

If you know your SQL you can tell this isn't exactly efficient.

Then runs through a foreach and nested foreach about 2000 times. While it's doing all this I can't submit the form until it's finished. This is all before I've even searched for anything.

When I do finally search ('tray' in this example) for something it takes ~25-30 seconds to get results. It runs the query mentioned above 6 times and runs foreach around 1800 times. The length of the search term is relative to processing time.

**Is this a problem that anyone else has experienced?**

**Is it something that I'm doing wrong?**

**Or is it just bad code by the CT team?**

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I am experiencing this myself.

Comment: It was passed on to another member of my team, so I'll try get a follow up for you tomorrow.

Comment: Do you use CE Cache/Any caching on your site?

Comment: I do use CE Cache.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this? The filter to search for products to add to a package takes at least 5 minutes to return results